# Split comma separated values in java, int and String

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I have the following in a text file to import into an ArrayList:

Australia,2

Ghana,4

China,3

Spain,1

My ArrayList is made up of objects from another class, Team which has the fields TeamName and ranking.  I can get the following to import the String and int into the team name, but I can't separate the number which is supposed to be the teams ranking:

```
  public void fileReader()
  {
    try
    {
        String filename = "teams.txt";
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(filename);
        Scanner parser = new Scanner(inputFile);

        for (Team teams : teams)
        {                 
            teams.setTeamName(parser.next());
            teams.setRanking(parser.next()); //this doesn't work
        }
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find file");
    }

}
```

I'm guessing I have to use a split somewhere along the line, or convert a String to an integer??

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.next()` read the next token from input stream, and give `String`.

If you want to read the next integer, you should use `nextInt()` instead:

```
teams.setRanking(parser.nextInt());
```

**Edit**

You got `InputMismatchException` because by default, `Scanner` use java whitespace as delimeter.

`WHITESPACE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\p{javaWhitespace}+")`

In your case, the delimeter are comma `,` and new line `\n` so you should config the delimeter for your scanner:

```
Scanner parser = new Scanner(inputFile);
s.useDelimiter(",|\\n")
```

Another work around is to read the whole line and parse your line:

```
String line = parse.nextLine();
String[] parts = line.split(",");
team.setTeamName(parts[0]);
team.setRanking(Integer.parse(parts[1]));
```

You can choose one of the two solutions above

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This compiles but I get an InputMismatchException when I run.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not getting back to you sooner.  This has worked and I'm very thankful.

Comment: While this works, I'm not sure my understanding of it is great.  The line String[] parts...is that creating an array then I am assigning the values to my arraylist?

Comment: `String[] parts = line.split(",");` will split your string based on `,` delimeter. If your line is "Ghana,4" then it give you array of string with two element ["Ghana", "4"]. Clear now?

Comment: But I recommend you using the first approach. It' easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out opencsv. It's 2018 and you shouldn't have to parse a text file yourself :).

Answer (score 0):

By default scanner will use white space as delimiter

Override this by calling useDelimiter method in your case parser.useDelimiter(',');

Then for converting ranking string to int you parser.nextInt()

Answer (score 0):

You can code something like below to suite your purpose.
You have two tokens in your use case i.e. comma (,) and new line (\n). As a result, next() can't be used in a straight forward way.

I am going over each line, then tokenizing each line on comma and finally getting subsequent tokens.

```
try
    {
        String filename = "teams.txt";
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(filename);
        Scanner parser = new Scanner(inputFile);

        for (Team teams : teams)
        {   
            String[] splitLine = sc.nextLine().split(","); // comma delimited array

            teams.setTeamName(splitLine[0]);
            teams.setRanking(splitLine[1]); 
        }
    }
```